# multi-user access to windows server 2012 via Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

I have a windows server 2012 in the office.

I want 5 users to be able to access it and work on it *at the same time*.

They are each connecting from their computers, in the same network, via Remote Desktop (Some windows, some mac).

Right now when we try to do it, the active user gets kicked out by the incoming user.

do I need to purchase CAL? which are the correct CAL to purchase?

Answer (score 1):

The built in remote desktop is only there for administering the server.  Two sessions are allowed at a time.

If you want multiple people connecting you need to install the remote desktop services role(s).  And buy a suitable number of remote desktop licenses.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the RDP licensing server and they give you a 90 day grace period, I believe. After that, it will still allow connections but you need to buy the licenses. You don't have to install them, but you need to keep them in a drawer for auditing purposes in case the Microsoft police come :-)